# Uniqueness of factorization $X=X_0\tilde A\tilde M$ of continuous semimartingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Suppose we're given a positive continuous semimartingale $X$ with standard decomposition $X=X_0+A+M$, where $A$ is continuous with paths of bounded variation on finite intervals and where $M$ is a local martingale, with $A_0=M_0=0$ a.s. Now I'm asked for a multiplicative decomposition $X_t=X_0\tilde A_t\tilde M_t$ where $\tilde A_0=\tilde M_0=1$, and where where $\tilde A$ is continuous with paths of bounded variation on finite intervals and where $\tilde M$ is a local martingale.

This can be solved using Itô's formula applied to $\log X$, yielding $$\tilde A=\exp\left(\int_0^{\cdot}\frac1X\ \mathrm dA\right)$$ and $$\tilde M=\mathcal E\left(\int_0^\cdot\frac1X\ \mathrm dM\right)=\exp\left(\int_0^{\cdot}\frac1X\ \mathrm dM-\frac12\int_0^{\cdot}\frac1{X^2}\ \mathrm d\langle M\rangle\right),$$ i.e. $\tilde M$ equals the Doléans exponential of $\int_0^\cdot\frac1X\ \mathrm dX$.

My question: is this decomposition unique? If so, why? I'm aware of the fact that the standard semimartingale decomposition $X=X_0+A+M$ is unique.

Comment: You wrote $\log{X}$ but is $X$ positive? The argument that the sum decomposition is unique is based on the fact that local mg with finite variation is a constant process. I think that might apply here too.

Comment: @Calculon Indeed, $X$ should be strictly positive, I forgot to mention. I know how the result you mention implies that the standard (i.e. additive) decomposition is unique, but I don't see how this applies here. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I haven’t thought this through, sorry. But $\log{X}$ is a semimartingale by Ito’s lemma and as such it admits a unique additive decomposition. Does that help?

Comment: I am aware of unicity of the additive decomposition, by the argument you mention. My question is about a multiplicative decomposition, for which I managed to prove existence and I'm asking here for the unicity of such a decomposition.

Comment: I meant there is a unique additive decomp for $\log{X}$.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see how a unique decomposition $\log X=\log X_0+\bar A+\bar M$ yields uniqueness of $X=X_0\tilde A\tilde M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X_t=X_0A_tM_t=X_0A'_tM'_t$, where $A,M,A',M'$ satisfy the given conditions. Then
\begin{align}
\log X_t &= \log X_0 + \log A_t + \log M_t\\
&= \log X_0 + \log A_t + \int_0^t \frac1{M_s}\,dM_s
- \frac12\int_0^t \frac1{M_s^2}\,d\langle M \rangle_s.
\end{align}
Similarly,
$$
\log X_t = \log X_0 + \log A'_t + \int_0^t \frac1{M'_s}\,dM'_s
- \frac12\int_0^t \frac1{(M'_s)^2}\,d\langle M' \rangle_s.
$$
Thus, the local martingale parts of these decompositions agree:
$$
\int_0^t \frac1{M_s}\,dM_s = \int_0^t \frac1{M'_s}\,dM'_s.
$$
The quadratic variation of the above local martingale is therefore
$$
\int_0^t \frac1{M_s^2}\,d\langle M \rangle_s
= \int_0^t \frac1{(M'_s)^2}\,d\langle M' \rangle_s.
$$
Together these show that $\log M_t = \log M'_t$, which implies $M = M'$, and hence, $A = A'$.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe worth mentioning is that we also need that when a process $Z$ is of b.v. over finite intervals, then so is $\log Z$, which follows by considering any partition $\Pi$ of a finite interval $[0,t]$  and since $Z$ is lower bounded by $\inf_{s\in[0,t]}Z_s>0$; we apply the MVT here.